# How to pull multiple xml elements in a CSV format using XQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am trying to pull multiple elements from an XML file using string-join function which works fine for a single element. However, when I try to add another one to my code I am seeing incorrect data. I suspect I'm missing a simple thing somewhere but can't seem to locate it..

sample XML data:-

```
<books>
  <book id="6636551">
    <master_information>
      <book_xref>
        <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">72771KAM3</xref>
        <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US72771KAM36</xref>
      </book_xref>
    </master_information>
    <book_details>
      <price>24.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
    </book_details>
    <global_information>
      <ratings>
        <rating agency="ABC Agency" type="Author Rating">A++</rating>
        <rating agency="DEF Agency" type="Author Rating">A+</rating>
        <rating agency="DEF Agency" type="Book Rating">A</rating>
      </ratings>
    </global_information>
    <country_info>
      <country_code>US</country_code>
    </country_info>
  </book>
  <book id="119818569">
    <master_information>
      <book_xref>
        <xref type="Fiction" type_id="1">070185UL5</xref>
        <xref type="Non_Fiction" type_id="2">US070185UL50</xref>
      </book_xref>
    </master_information>
    <book_details>
      <price>19.25</price>
      <publish_date>2002-11-01</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
    </book_details>
    <global_information>
      <ratings>
        <rating agency="ABC Agency" type="Author Rating">A+</rating>
        <rating agency="ABC Agency" type="Book Rating">A</rating>
        <rating agency="DEF Agency" type="Author Rating">A</rating>
        <rating agency="DEF Agency" type="Book Rating">B+</rating>
      </ratings>
    </global_information>
    <country_info>
      <country_code>CA</country_code>
    </country_info>
  </book>
  </book>
</books>
```

XQuery for pulling a single element:-

```
for $x in string-join(('book_id,book_price', //book/book_details/price/string-join((ancestor::book/@id, .), ',')), '&#10;')
return $x
```

Which works fine, and spits sample output as follows:

```
book_id,book_price
6636551,24.95
119818569,19.25
```

Question is how do I pull **multiple** elements or a combination of elements and attributes, still using string-join probably, from a single XML file?

I tried using the following (which works OK for the most part) but I noticed for a larger data set the values seem to be **populating in the wrong column** randomly. E.g. in the code below if `./publish_date` is blank in the data I noticed `./description` data would get populated in the `./publish_date` column.

```
for $x in string-join(('book_id,book_price,book_pub_date,book_desc', //book/book_details/string-join((ancestor::book/@id, ./price, ./publish_date, ./description), ',')), '&#10;')
return $x
```

FYI, I'm still learning XQuery as you can tell. I appreciate your insights/opinions/help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequences in XQuery are *flattened*: The expressions `(1, (2, 3), ((4)), (), 5)` and `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` are equivalent. This means that the length of the sequence `(ancestor::book/@id, ./price, ./publish_date, ./description)` varies if some of the XPath subqueries return no results.  Since the function `fn:string-join($strings, $sep)` just puts the separatur between every pair of adjacent items in `$strings` (flattened), the resulting string can have a varying number of commas in it.

In order to preserve the alignment of your CSV table you can insert empty strings whenever a value is missing. An easy way to do that is using flattening to its advantage: `($possibly-empty, '')[1]`

- If `$possibly-empty` contains an item (e.g. `'foo'`) then this evaluates to `('foo', '')[1]` -> `'foo'`.
- If it is the empty sequence `()` instead, the expression evaluates to `((), '')[1]` -> `('')[1]` (flattening) -> `''`.

Working example (your enclosing FLWOR expression (`for`/`return`) is completely redundant because you only iterate over a single string element, so I omit it):

```
string-join(
  (
    'book_id,book_price,book_pub_date,book_desc',
    //book/book_details/string-join(
      (
        (ancestor::book/@id, '')[1],
        (./price, '')[1],
        (./publish_date, '')[1],
        (./description, '')[1]
      ),
      ','
    )
  ),
  '&#10;'
)
```

You can also abstract that functionality out into its own function:

```
declare function local:non-empty($possibly-empty) {
  ($possibly-empty, '')[1]
};

string-join(
  (
    'book_id,book_price,book_pub_date,book_desc',
    //book/book_details/string-join(
      (
        local:non-empty(ancestor::book/@id),
        local:non-empty(./price),
        local:non-empty(./publish_date),
        local:non-empty(./description)
      ),
      ','
    )
  ),
  '&#10;'
)
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks much, Leo. Couldn't have asked for a more precise and organized answer. For my edification, why do you add "[1]" - what does that do?

Comment: The bracketed part after an XQuery expression is a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates), and -- because the content is numeric -- a positional predicate. it takes the sequence of items produced by the expression in front of it and returns the item at the given position (or an empty sequence if no such item exists). So `('foo', 123, <x/>, 'asd')[2]` returns `123`. In my code I want to return either the first (and only) item in the input sequence or the empty string I added myself. Without the `[1]` the first case would result in a two-item sequence.